# How to promote a pod to a deployment for scaling

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running the example in chapter "Service Discovery" of the book "Kubernetes up and running". The original command to run a deployment is `kubectl run alpaca-prod --image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue --replicas=3 --port=8080 --labels="ver=1,app=alpaca,env=prod"`, however in K8s version 1.25, the `--replicate` parameter in run command is not supported any more. I planned to run without replica and then use "kubectl scale" to scale the deployment later. Problem is the run command only creates a pod, not a deployment (the scale command expects a deployment). So how do i promote my pod to a deployment, my kubernetes verion is 1.25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to promote it however you can change label and all those stuff but instead of that you can create the new deployment delete the existing POD.

So easy step you can take input of existing running POD to YAML file first

```
kubectl get pod <POD name> -o yaml > pod-spec.yaml
```

Create deployment spec YAML file now

```
kubectl create deployment deploymentname --image=imagename --dry-run=client -o yaml > deployment-spec.yaml
```

Edit the **deployment-spec.yaml** file

and in other tab **pod-spec.yaml** you can copy the Spec part from POD file to new deployment file.

Once **deployment-spec.yaml** is ready you can apply it. Make sure if you are running service labels get matched properly

```
kubectl apply -f deployment-spec.yaml
```

Delete the single running POD

```
kubectl delete pod <POD name>
```